# Custom Oracle webcenter WCC workflow emails

Tags: oracle11g, content-management-system, oracle12c, webcenter, oracle-ucm

In Oracle Webcenter content WCC(aka UCM/ECM) need to change the content(Title, Body etc.) of the automated workflow emails received during approval/rejection. Please share in detail how to change the template and/or override the component

I tried changing the review/reject template at below core location but still received the original emails only.
/product/Oracle_Home/wccontent/ucm/idc/resources/core/templates

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to [learn how to use the Component Wizard](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wcc/webcenter-content-develop/GUID-3259ABFD-F7F8-4F89-8CA1-C622870878CF.htm#WCCDV139). Once you have it running and you have a basic understanding of how to use it, you will be able to create *Components*. That is the correct way of overriding and adding functionality of your WCC installation. Never change the content of the ucm/idc/resources/ folder.

The first resources to override are

- `<@dynamichtml wf_approve_mail_subject@>`
- Relevant templates with formtype=WorkflowMail

Comment: @sam- Thanks a lot but i) the link doesn't have the info. how to over ride or achieve my requirement ii) I've always found  Oracle document/s a bible with lot of relevant as well as irrelevant info. to the topic. and I've seen (mostly in Webcenter forums),  users sharing complete books/chapters for an answer. Sorry, but it is not what questioner is looking for.  Apart from that, the 2nd part of the answer was helpful but would still need more specific info.

Comment: The only irrelevant part of that page is the last subsection, 12.4. All the rest are the parts you need to understand to customize WCC.

Comment: on another note - Is it possible to launch DIS with a link. I would like to give the DIS Client 'My workflow assignments' link rather than the web(browser) link in the workflow emails.  I see the application do not launches from installed location C:\Program Files\Oracle\WebCenter Desktop\Content\Windows Explorer Integration. I can customize the email but how to launch DIS from a link in the email? Regards

Comment: I wish I knew. If you find out, please share